# Using user inputs from readline to compute summaries of variables of a database in r studio

Tags: dataframe, readline, summary

I am working with a large database. 35682 obs and 256 variables. I would like to create a data frame with the summary of certain variables. My idea is to ask the user to write the names of the variables and then to compute the summary of those variables. To ask for the variable names I have coded this:

```
prompt <- "Digite el nombre de las variables separadas por un espacio: "
EXP <- as.vector(strsplit(readline(prompt), " ")[[1]])
```

This vector contains the name of some variables of the large data base, the ones that the user is interested in. To create the data frame I used this code:

```
DescriptivosII_III2017 <- data.frame(variables,mean, max, min,desvest)
```

And what I need to do now is to get the names out of that vector and let r know that these names are the names of some variables in the big data base. And that it must compute the summary of all of those variables and add that info to the data frame. How can I do this?